# Path-finding using only neural network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, path-finding

I'm trying to train a neural network for a path-finding problem on **10x10 grid map** but it seems it doesn't work. Here is the details:

My input to the neural network is 10x10x2 matrix where first 10x10 represents **obstacles** on the map, second 10x10 represents only two points, **initial and final points**.

My output to the system is the shorthest path found by A* algorithm. I've written a code that produces desired number of cases, and the optimal route is found by A* just after producing the case. I want to teach finding this paths to neural network. As an example, the general structure for 4x4 case is like below.

```
obstacles matrix(input):
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0

initial and final point matrix(input):
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 

route(desired output):
1 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
```

Also, I'm adding the pictures of a case and the output of neural network.

obstacles

[image: obstacles]

start and target points

[image: start and target points]

desired route

[image: desired route]

combined image

[image: combined image]

**Up to now**, I've described the inputs and output of the neural network. I'm trying to train network using 3 fully connected layer but it seems it does not learn the pattern. Here is my network:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,10,10,2])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,10,10])
rate = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

# flatten the input
x_flatten = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)
y_flatten = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(y)

# fully connected layer
fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x_flatten, units=1000, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
fc = tf.layers.dropout(fc, rate=rate, training=True) # rate = 0.3
fc = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc,        units=500, activation=tf.nn.tanh)
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc,    units=100, activation=None)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(logits - y_flatten))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
```

Finally, I'm adding the outcome of the NN after training with 1000 cases and 20 epochs, and the ground truth together.

training outcome

[image: training outcome]

test outcome

[image: test outcome]

I have also tried CNN but it also did not work. Any suggestions will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just too broad, but in general I don't think you will be able to ever get a good result with this. Neural networks are not really well suited to the problem of path finding, at least not in this form. You may get the network to learn specific training examples, but it's nearly impossible to get a good general path finder this way. These kind of problems are more typically approached through reinforcement learning... and even then, it's very hard for the neural net to "understand" the concept of connectivity from the image. Standard path finding algorithms will always work better.

Comment: thank you for your answer. you sound logical but on the otherhand, the problem looks so simple so it seems the nn can learn the logic.

Comment: Probably a Recurrent Neural Network can get some decent result.

Comment: I just wonder if it can be done with NNs, thank you for your answer. I'll try RNNs.

Comment: Probably not related, but just a side note that in combined image it's quite hard to say whether the white blocks are obstacles, or is that white blocks are obstacles. I initially thought the white are obstacles, and found that it's not optimal way, but only then realized that's not optimal because obstacles are not the whites